# On the Alpine Linux Docker Image, I get `nvm: command not found`

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, docker, nvm

I have read the README of the nvm project, which lists the packages I need to install, although I had to modify the `python2` package to `python3`, since the former package was deprecated following Alpine 3.13 release, as node can run on `python3` package. Here is my Dockerfile, which is meant to be part of my `.devcontainer` directory to run on a Codespace:

```
# Pull the Alpine 3.15 Docker image
FROM alpine:3.16

# Enter the BASH shell
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]

# Add packages without caching, but while upgrading Alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache -U\
    curl bash ca-certificates\
    openssl ncurses coreutils\
    python3 make gcc g++\
    libgcc linux-headers grep\
    util-linux binutils findutils

RUN touch ~/.bashrc

# Install NVM and source it
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
RUN echo '\
export NVM_DIR="~/.nvm" \
[-s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
[[ -r $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ]] && \. $NVM_DIR/bash_completion\
' >~/.bashrc

# Run the usual setup NVM commands
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "nvm install -s --lts --latest-npm" ]
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "nvm alias default lts/*" ]

# Install NPM packages and run the dev server
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "npm i" ]
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "npm run dev" ]
```

Here is the line in my `creation.log` file which denotes the error:

```
2022-09-27 14:44:57.546Z: #9 [6/8] RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "nvm install -s --lts --latest-npm" ]
2022-09-27 14:44:58.134Z: #9 0.539 /bin/bash: line 1: nvm: command not found
2022-09-27 14:44:58.229Z: #9 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/bash -c nvm install -s --lts --latest-npm]: exit code: 127
```

If anything else is needed, please let me know! Thanks for any help!

Comment: `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive shell use. Furthermore, `nvm.sh` needs to be sourced (not executed) for the `nvm` command to work, so you cannot simply update the `PATH`.

Comment: `nvm` is strange to see inside of docker because it's a tool for managing multiple node versions, but it would be very odd to have 2 different versions in the same container. Any reason to not use the nodejs image for your desired version instead?

Comment: In a codespace, it is seemingly locked to Node v14.19.0, but'll try that.

Comment: That worked, I just need to install GIT, could you post that as an answer, and I’ll mark it as an Answer, @jordanm?

Comment: Why would you use nvm in the first place inside a container? Just pull the specific node image you want to run...

Comment: I figured out a fix myself, but I have marked the most relevant answer as correct.

Comment: @LukeBatema, you should share you answer

Comment: Okay, I will share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Pull the Alpine 3.15 Docker image
FROM alpine:3.15

# Set the entrypoint to the `ASH` shell
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash"]

# Add the needed packages without caching, but upgrading Alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache -U npm nodejs sudo git

RUN git config --global user.email lukasbatema@gmail.com
RUN git config --global user.name BatemaDevelopment

# Add the `node` group and user, then assign the user to the group
RUN addgroup -S node && adduser -S node -G node

# Make the directory and subdirectories `/home/node/acoustic-docs/node_modules`
# and change ownership recursivly to the `node` user and group
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs

# Make the required directories for the docs
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/blog && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs/blog
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/Buttons && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs/Buttons
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/docs && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs/docs
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/src && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs/src
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/acoustic-docs/static && chown -R node:node /home/node/acoustic-docs/static

# Set the working directory to `/home/node/acoustic-docs`
WORKDIR /home/node/acoustic-docs

COPY --chown=node:node . .

CMD [ "npm", "run dev" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Version managers like `nvm` largely don't work in Docker.  In particular, most paths to running Docker containers and individual `RUN` commands don't read the `.bashrc` file or any other shell dotfiles; so if the only thing that adds `nvm` to `$PATH` is code in the `.bashrc` file, that is why you're getting the `nvm: command not found` error.

You should be able to replace the first two thirds of the Dockerfile with just

```bash
FROM node:lts
```

See the [Docker Hub `node` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) for more details on what's in the image.  This includes the Node interpreter itself, NPM, and Yarn.  The default `node` image is based on Debian, so if you do need to install other packages (like a Python interpreter to run `node-gyp`) you'll need to use `apt-get` and not `apk` to install them.

Your Dockerfile will run into a couple of other notable problems.  You need to `COPY` the package metadata into the image before you can run `npm install`; and then you need to `COPY` the application code in before you run the application itself.  A corrected Dockerfile should look more like

```bash
FROM node:lts
# RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ...
WORKDIR /app     # don't install into filesystem root
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i        # or npm ci
COPY ./ ./       # make sure node_modules is in .dockerignore
CMD npm run dev  # or something that doesn't run a dev server
```

I've avoided `RUN ["sh", "-c", "..."]` syntax: Docker automatically inserts the `sh -c` wrapper if `RUN` or `CMD` is a bare string.  I've also skipped the problematic `ENTRYPOINT` line, which will limit your image to only running commands that happen to be interpreted as shell scripts.

Comment: Although this works, I found another way that does what I need in the way I prefer, without using NVM.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be using `alpine` based image for python/Node applications,

**Standard PyPI wheels don’t work on Alpine**

Most Python packages these days include binary wheels on PyPI, significantly speeding install time. But if you’re using Alpine Linux you need to compile all the C code in every Python package that you use.

See here eventual issues you can have
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

**Update**

As for Node Applications

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA8wtTUCdgc

You can end up resolving this, then another one will show up and so on and on...

Comment: (This appears to be a Node application.)

Comment: @DavidMaze same goes for Node application, check my edit

Comment: I realise I need to compile the header files, as I have been through the need of resolving one, just to go on to another, but this is what I want to do.

Comment: I do think this is a helpful comment for other people to consider as well, so I upvoted it :)